# How do both of these function pointer calling syntax variations work?

Tags: c

I'm relatively new to C, and found it intriguing that both of the following calls to the function pointer compile and work fine. One with and one without dereferencing the function pointer before calling it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void func() {
    puts("I'm a func");
}
int main(void) {
    void (*f)() = func;
    f();
    (*f)();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I think I understand that `(*f)()` is the "official" way to call a function pointer, but why does simply calling `f()` work? Is that syntactic sugar of recent C versions?

Comment: It's not recent. And if you think about it, you can view calling a function directly the same as by invoking it through a const pointer.

Comment: `(*f)()`? Why not `(****f)()`?

Comment: Thanks! the C community on SO rocks :) appreciate your patience for a C noob like me!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a piece of syntactic/semantic sugar that has, AFAIK, worked since the very earliest versions of C. It makes sense if you think of functions as pointers to code.

The only special rule needed to make function pointers work this way is that indirecting a function pointer gives the same pointer back (because you can't manipulate code in standard C anyway): when `f` is a function pointer, then `f == (*f) == (**f)`, etc.

(Aside: watch out with declaration such as `void (*f)()`. An empty argument list denotes an old-style, pre-C89 function declaration that matches on the return type only. Prefer `void (*f)(void)` for type safety.)

Answer (score 5):

In C you can call your function like:

```
f();
(*f)();
(**f)();
(********f)();
(*****************************f)();
```

all are valid. In C, dereferencing or taking the address of a function just evaluates to a pointer to that function, and dereferencing a function pointer just evaluates back to the function pointer. C is designed in such a way that both function name identifier as well as variable holding function's pointer mean the same: **address to CODE memory**. And it allows to jump to that memory by using call `()` syntax either on an identifier or variable.
And the last but but least, standard says that:

#### C11: 6.3.2.1:

> 4    A function designator is an expression that has function type. Except when it is the
>   operand of the `sizeof` operator, the `_Alignof` operator,65) or the unary `&` operator, a
>   function designator with type ‘‘function returning type’’ is converted to an expression that has type ‘‘pointer to function returning type’’.

Comment: Good, but why is that?

Answer (score 5):

A function call expression is always of the form "function pointer", "round parenthesis", "arguments", "round parenthesis". In order for you not to have to spell out `(&printf)("Hello World\n")` every time<sup>1</sup>, there is a separate rule by which an expression which denotes a function decays to the respective function pointer.

Since a function pointer can be dereferenced to give an expression that denotes a function again, this will again decay, so you can keep dereferencing and there'll be a lot of decay:

```
(&f)();   // no decay (decay does not happen when the expression
          //           is the operand of &)
f();      // one decay
(*f)();   // two decays
(**f)();  // three decays
```

<sup>1) Early Perl has function syntax like that.</sup>

Comment: The funny thing is that `(&printf)("Hello")` is the same as `(*printf)("Hello")`. I wouldn't even have thought of writing the former.

Answer (score 5):

The C 2011 standard says in clause 6.3.2.1, paragraph 4:

> Except when it is the operand of the **sizeof operator**, the **_Alignof** operator, or the unary **&** operator, a function designator with type ‘‘function returning *type*’’ is converted to an expression that has type ‘‘pointer to function returning *type*’’.

This means that, if `f` designates a function, then, in a call such as `f()`, `f` is automatically converted to `&f`, resulting in `(&f)()`. This is actually the “proper” way to call a function, because the function-call expression requires a pointer to a function.

Now consider what happens in `*f`. The `f` is automatically converted to `&f`, so we have `*&f`. In this expression, the result of the `*` operator is a function, `f`; it just reverses the operation performed by `&`. So `*&f` is the same as `f`. We can repeat this indefinitely: `**f` is automatically converted to `**&f`, which is `*f`, which is automatically converted to `*&f`, which is `f`, which is automatically converted to `&f`.